# « D’elle, sur elle, sur son compte, à son sujet »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Johanne s’est formalisée de ce que Christian a dit d’elle.

> Johanne s’est formalisée de ce que Christian a dit sur elle.

> Johanne s’est formalisée de ce que Christian a dit sur son compte.

> Johanne s’est formalisée de ce que Christian a dit à son sujet.

*edit

D’autres formulations qui me viennent à l’idée:

> Johanne s’est formalisée des propos que Christian a tenus sur son compte.

> Johanne s’est formalisée des propos que Christian a tenus sur elle.

> Johanne s’est formalisée des propos que Christian a tenus d’elle.

N’hésitez pas à proposer d’autres énonciations plus élégantes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toutes ces variantes sont valides et essentiellement synonymes. *Sur elle* et *sur son compte* peuvent être perçus comme légèrement plus offensants.